# List of places where Elokim is written as tetragrammaton

Tags: hebrew, torah-reading, pronunciation, shemos-sacred-names

Can someone point me to a list of all places in Tanach where the tetragrammaton is pronounced as "Elokim" (as in, e.g., Yechezkel 28:25)? For some reason, my concordance does not list these under either the "Elokim" or tetragrammaton entries.

Comment: JSYK, these names aren’t actually Elokim. That’s just our tradition of how to pronounce them.

Answer (score 2):

Searching Sefaria for א-דני י-הוה yields the following results:

- Bereishis 15:2, 15:8
- Devarim 3:24, 9:26
- Yehoshua 7:7
- Shoftim 6:22, 16:28
- Shmuel 1:25:28, 2:7:18, 2:7:19, 2:7:20, 2:7:22, 2:7:28, 2:7:29
- Melachim 1:2:26, 1:8:53
- Yeshaya 3:15, 7:7, 10:23, 10:24, 22:5, 22:12, 22:14, 22:15, 25:8, 28:16, 28:22, 30:15, 40:10, 48:16, 49:22, 50:4, 50:5, 50:7, 50:9, 52:4, 56:8, 61:1, 61:11, 65:13, 65:15
- Yirmiya 1:6, 2:19, 2:22, 4:10, 7:20, 14:13, 32:17, 32:25, 44:26, 46:10, 49:5, 50:25, 50:31
- Yechezkel 2:4, 3:11, 3:27, 4:14, 5:5, 5:7, 5:8, 5:11, 6:3, 6:11, 7:2, 7:5, 8:1, 9:8, 11:7, 11:8, 11:13, 11:16, 11:17, 11:21, 12:10, 12:19, 12:23, 12:25, 12:28, 13:3, 13:8, 13:9, 13:13, 13:16, 13:18, 13:20, 14:4, 14:6, 14:11, 14:14, 14:16, 14:18, 14:20, 14:21, 14:23, 15:6, 15:8, 16:3, 16:8, 16:14, 16:19, 16:23, 16:30, 16:36, 16:43, 16:48, 16:59, 16:63, 17:3, 17:9, 17:16, 17:19, 17:22, 18:3, 18:9, 18:23, 18:30, 18:32, 20:3, 20:5, 20:27, 20:30, 20:31, 20:33, 20:36, 20:39, 20:40, 20:44, 21:3, 21:5, 21:12, 21:18, 21:29, 21:31, 21:33, 22:3, 22:12, 22:19, 22:28, 22:31, 23:22, 23:28, 23:32, 23:34, 23:35, 23:46, 23:49, 24:3, 24:6, 24:9, 24:14, 24:21, 24:24, 25:3, 25:6, 25:8, 25:12, 25:13, 25:14, 25:15, 25:16, 26:3, 26:5, 26:7, 26:14, 26:15, 26:19, 26:21, 27:3, 28:2, 28:6, 28:10, 28:12, 28:22, 28:24, 28:25, 29:3, 29:8, 29:13, 29:16, 29:19, 29:20, 30:2, 30:6, 30:10, 30:13, 30:22, 31:10, 31:15, 31:18, 32:3, 32:8, 32:11, 32:14, 32:16, 32:31, 32:32, 33:11, 33:25, 33:27, 34:2, 34:8, 34:10, 34:11, 34:15, 34:17, 34:20, 34:30, 34:31, 35:3, 35:6, 35:11, 35:14, 36:2, 26:3, 36:4, 36:5, 36:6, 36:7, 36:13, 36:14, 36:15, 36:22, 36:23, 36:32, 36:33, 36:37, 37:3, 37:5, 37:9, 37:12, 37:19, 37:21, 38:3, 38:10, 38:14, 38:17, 38:18, 38:21, 39:1, 39:5, 39:8, 39:10, 39:13, 39:17, 39:20, 39:25, 39:29, 43:18, 43:19, 43:27, 44:6, 44:9, 44:12, 44:15, 44:27, 45:9, 45:15, 45:18, 46:1, 46:16, 47:13, 47:23, 48:29
- Amos 1:8, 3:7, 3:8, 3:11, 4:2, 4:5, 5:3, 6:8, 7:1, 7:2, 7:4, 7:5, 7:6, 8:1, 8:3, 8:9, 8:11, 9:5, 9:8
- Ovadiah 1:1
- Michah 1:2
- Chavakuk 3:19
- Tzefaniah 1:7
- Zechariah 9:14
- Tehillim 68:21, 69:7, 71:5, 71:16, 73:28, 109:21, 140:8, 141:8

I believe the word only appears in this Name pair, or the opposite order. Even if it doesn’t, it’s so sparingly that this should give you the overwhelming majority. Many of these have multiple occurrences within the verse. In total, that adds up to about 300 pesukim, over 200 of which are in Yechezkel alone.

Comment: It also shows up as יהוה אדני in the other order. Does your search catch those?

Comment: @DoubleAA It does, since Sefaria’s search engine breaks on Tanach if I do exact search. So it will flag a passuk if both words appear in it, regardless of the order or if they’re even next to each other. I only saw one such passuk, but if you catch others that I missed, feel free to edit them in.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! But actually I was exactly curious whether this ever happens OTHER than in this name pair (or its opposite).

Comment: @user6584 I’m not sure where you’re saying that in your question. You just ask where this word appears, not where it appears alone. I’m tempted to say that it doesn’t appear alone.

Comment: I am looking for all places where this word appears. The list you provided includes all places where it appears as a name pair. I am trying to understand if there are other places where it does not appear as a name pair.

Comment: @user6584 Got it. That I can’t help you with, but I suspect it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @user6584 it only appears in that pairing, in either order. If it were pronounced Adonai Adonai then there'd be no way to tell you meant two different names so we switch to a different name of God. Remember in any event we're not actually pronouncing the Tetragrammaton correctly. We always substitute in a different name (referring always to the same entity of course, namely God). So we just pick a different one in those contexts.

Comment: FWIW, the list provided by DonielF appears to be neither completely accurate nor complete. Specifically, I don't find an occurrence in Shmuel I 25:28 (even though that verse is listed above), and there is an occurrence in Amos 3:13 (even though that verse is not listed above).