# Hashem Elokim in Torah

Tags: tanach, shemos-sacred-names

In the second chapter of Bereishit, God is referred to as "Hashem Elokim". As far as I know, this seems to be a rare phenomenon. (Note, it is pretty common to have 2 names of God next to each other pronounced as Hashem Elokim, as in the second pasuk of veschanan, but I refer to when these words actually appear in the text.)

Does anyone know where else this name appears in Tanach?

Comment: I assume you mean as יקוק אלקים, as spelled in Bereishis ch. 2 and 3, as opposed to א-דני יקוק, a similar phenomenon discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94352/)?

Comment: exactly. That is what I was getting to in the parenthesis in my question. I am interested in the appearance of those exact 2 words next to each other. I am curious if it is a unique name to gan eden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sefaria's a bit glitchy today. I attempted [this Sefaria search](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=0&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance), but it's pulling any passuk which contains any form of the root אלה, rather than specifically the Name יקוק אלקים as "exact search" should do. So I used my browser's search-on-page feature to filter just the results containing the requested Name. Excluding all results from Bereishis chapters 2 and 3, we find:

- Shemos 9:30: ואתה ועבדיך ידעתי כי טרם תיראון מפני ה׳ אלקים, "You and your servants I know do not yet fear Hashem Elokim."
- Shmuel II:7:25: ועתה ה׳ אלקים הדבר אשר דברת על עבדך ועל ביתו הקם עד עולם ועשה כאשר דברת, "And now, Hashem Elokim - this thing which you have spoken regarding Your servant and regarding Your house, uphold it forever and do as You have spoken."
- Melachim II:19:19: ועתה ה׳ אלקינו הושענו נא מידו וידעו כל ממלכות הארץ כי אתה ה׳ אלקים לבדך, "And now, Hashem our G-d, save us please from his hand, and all the kingdoms of the land will know that You alone are Hashem Elokim."
- Tehillim 72:18: ברוך ה׳ אלקים אלקי ישראל עשה נפלאות לבדו, "Blessed is Hashem Elokim, the G-d of Israel, Who alone does wonders."
- Tehillim 80:5: ה׳ אלקים צבא-ות עד מתי עשנת בתפלת עמך, "Hashem Elokim of Legions, until when will you be wrathful of the prayers of Your people?!"
- Tehillim 80:20: ה׳ אלקים צבא-ות השיבנו האר פניך ונושעה, "Hashem Elokim of Legions, save us; show us Your favor that we may be saved."
- Tehillim 84:9: ה׳ אלקים צבא-ות שמעה תפלתי האזינה אלקי יעקב סלה, "Hashem Elokim of Legions, hear my prayer; listen, G-d of Yaakov, Selah."
- Tehillim 84:12: כי שמש ומגן ה׳ אלקים חן וכבוד יתן ה׳ לא ימנע טוב להלכים בתמים, "For a sun and protector is Hashem Elokim. Grace and honor will Hashem give; He will not withhold good from those who go in perfection."
- Divrei HaYamim I:17:16-17: ויבא המלך דויד וישב לפני ה׳  ויאמר מי אני ה׳ אלקים ומי ביתי כי הביאתני עד הלם ותקטן זאת בעיניך ותדבר על בית עבדך למרחוק וראיתני כתור האדם המעלה ה׳ אלקים, "And the King David came and sat before Hashem and said, 'Who am I, Hashem Elokim, and who is my household that You have brought me here? And this has become small in Your eyes, that You speak regarding the house of Your servant for the future. You see me as a man of distinction, Hashem Elokim.'"
- Divrei HaYamim I:28:20: ויאמר דויד לשלמה בנו חזק ואמץ ועשה אל תירא ואל תחת כי ה׳ אלקים אלקי עמך לא ירפך ולא יעזבך עד לכלות כל מלאכת עבודת בית ה׳, "And David said to Shlomo his son, 'Be strong and courageous. Do, do not fear and do not be discouraged, for Hashem Elokim, my G-d, is with you; He will not weaken you nor abandon you until the completion of all the work of the service of the House of Hashem.'"
- Divrei HaYamim II:1:9: עתה ה׳ אלקים יאמן דברך עם דויד אבי כי אתה המלכתני על עם רב כעפר הארץ, "'Now, Hashem Elokim, be true to Your word with David my father, for You have crowned me over a nation vast as the dust of the earth.'"
- Divrei HaYamim II:6:41-42: ועתה קומה ה׳ אלקים לנוחך אתה וארון עזך כהניך ה׳ אלקים ילבשו תשועה וחסידיך ישמחו בטוב ה׳ אלקים אל תשב פני משיחיך זכרה לחסדי דויד עבדך, "'And now, arise, Hashem Elokim, to Your resting place, You and the Ark of Your strength. Your priests, Hashem Elokim, will don salvation, and Your pious ones will rejoice in goodness. Hashem Elokim, do not turn from the face of Your anointed one; remember the kindness of David, Your servant.'"

That's a total of fifteen occurrences outside Parshas Bereishis: one in the Torah (in Shemos), two in Neviim (one in each Shmuel and Melachim), and twelve in Kesuvim (five in Tehillim, seven in Divrei HaYamim).

Comment: The logical follow-up question, I suppose, is if there's a guiding principle that links all of these passages to Gan Eden.

Comment: thanks for the great answer! I'm gonna have to think myself if I can somehow find a link. The one in shemos is especially interesting.